# Receiving Emails on Hosting Domain Email Id from any user visiting to site

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am trying to create a contact us page where visitor of the site can leave a message to site-admin.

say I m running this site
www.example.com
and i have an id contact@example.com
Now a new visitor visits my site and fills up the contact us form. 
He fills

FROM - abc@yahoo.com
Subject- Query
Message- My question....

I want to send this message as a mail to contact@example.com

And on successfull sending of mail i want to send this user autogenerated mail as an acknowledgement.

What I need to do for this, My hosting server is GoDaddy

I am trying the following code.

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text);
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("contact@example.com"));
        mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mailMessage.Body = txtMessage.Text;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
        //sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("contact@example.com", "MyPassword");
        sc.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "An Error has occured : "+ex.Message;
    }
```

This error occurs while trying to send mail.

> Mailbox name not allowed. The server
>   response was: sorry, your mail was
>   administratively denied. (#5.7.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from your code you are specifying that the mail message's `From` field is based on the email address the user fills in. The mail server mail be rejecting this and only allowing email from the domain name `example.com` or perhaps the server name itself. I've run into this before where your `From` field must be the original site domain...

If you want to have the ability for the form-mail recipient to directly reply, use the [ReplyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replyto.aspx) field rather than the from:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

//try using a domain address that matches your server and/or site.
//the email address itself may also have to exist depending on the mail server.
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@example.com");

//set the replyto field
mailMessage.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text);

//send the mail...
```

Hope this might help...

**EDIT:**

After you've edited your question, the above is still relevant. It's very likely you cannot use a `From` address outside of your own site domain `example.com`. If you want to send two copies of the request (one to contact@example.com and the other to the user as an acknowledgment), you simply need to add to the `To` property:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

//try using a domain address that matches your server and/or site.
//the email address itself may also have to exist depending on the mail server.
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@example.com");

//add the contact email address to the To list
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("contact@example.com"));

//add the user email address to the To list
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text));

//set the replyto field
mailMessage.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text);

//send the mail...
```

If you need to add a simple message for the user acknowledgment email you could also do:

```
try
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@example.com");
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("contact@example.com"));
    mailMessage.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text);
    mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    mailMessage.Body = txtMessage.Text;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
    //sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("contact@example.com", "MyPassword");

    //send to only the contact@example.com first
    sc.Send(mailMessage);

    mailMessage.To.Clear();
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmailId.Text));

    //add a simple message to the user at the beginning of the body
    mailMessage.Body = "Thank you for submitting your question. The following has been submitted to contact@example.com: <br/><br/>" + mailMessage.Body;

    //send the acknowledgment message to the user
    sc.Send(mailMessage);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label1.Text = "An Error has occured : "+ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: @KP u r right, But thr was some mistake in xplaining Q, Plz check the Edit

Answer (score 0):

It is probably [**Serverfault.com**](https://serverfault.com/) question, any how

you need to check these options

> Admin Home -> Configuration -> Email
>   Options -> - E-Mail Transport Method =
>   sendemail

reference [**553 sorry, your mail was administratively denied**](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=709521). (#5.7.1)

Comment: @Asad thr was some mistake in xplaining Q, Plz check the Edit

Comment: can you plz mark your editions under "EDIT", i cannot get you editions